# Redirect WSL input in Powershell

Tags: powershell, authentication, automation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, start-process

I've been trying to write a powershell script that automates my windows workspace setup and configuration and am currently stuck trying to redirect input to WSL when executing it for the first time. The core of the problem is that Ubuntu's first launch prompts for a username and password, then logs in to a bash shell. I tried writing down the input lines into a text file like so:

```
Username
Password
Password
exit
```

Then, I tried redirecting the input of wsl to the file:

```
Start-Process ubuntu2004.exe -RedirectStandardInput stdin.txt -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

The above didn't work as executing WSL just starts spamming `Enter new UNIX username: adduser: only one or two names allowed`. I tried doing same in CMD with the `<` input redirection, but the result is the same.

Comment: Try `Get-Content stdin.txt | .\ubuntu2004.exe`

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/a/1111036

Comment: @zett42 Sadly, the `Get-Content` doesn't work because it passes the return value of the cmdlet as arguments, not through stdin

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas for setting the username/password in a new Ubuntu WSL instance:

- First, a ["PowerShell sendkeys" via COM or Interop](https://superuser.com/a/1250038/1210833) might work for this.  It's probably the closest in behavior to what you are actually asking.
- Second, and perhaps most promising, I just tried this with a new Debian WSL installed from the Store (since I didn't want to mess with my Ubuntu install).

  When running `debian.exe` (like `ubuntu2004.exe`), I let it run the install, then I Ctrl+C'd out of it when it started asking for the default username/password.  At that point, the WSL instance is installed, but with only root.  I assume that your script can let the command run for a certain period of time, then kill the process to replicate this.

  From your script, you should then be able to run `wsl -u root useradd --create-home --user-group --groups  adm,dialout,cdrom,floppy,sudo,audio,dip,video,plugdev,netdev --password "encryptedPassword" username` (see [here](https://serverfault.com/a/367569/607123) for creating the encrypted password).  I think that will get you a stock Ubuntu user the way that WSL sets it up.

  You'll then need to either create a `/etc/wsl.conf` file ([instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#user)) letting the instance know that that user is the default, or [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) lists this as one of its features.
- But I'd also throw in that you might just want to keep a "backup" of an existing WSL instance that you start from.  Do a `wsl --export <distroname> <imagename.tgz>`, then you can import it when setting up the new Windows host by copying the `tgz` over and doing a `wsl --import <DistroName> <DirectoryWhereYouwantItToLive> <imagename.tgz>`.

  If you want, you can keep this image up to date with your desired WSL configuration, so that you don't have to recreate it when you rebuild the Windows hosts.  That said, this is where I do follow @Mystic's suggestion of using Ansible to store my WSL "configuration as code".  It allows me to not only recreate my WSL instances, but also that same configuration when I set (or reset) a Linode host or another Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer to your question, but in my opinion, `ansible` is better suited for such a task.
I myself recently became interested in assembling a workspace in wsl and ansible seemed to me the best solution.
Before starting the build, you will need to perform minimal steps (create a user and install several packages, all this can be placed in the readme), but then there will be no restrictions.
You can find several ready-made examples of wsl assembly via ansible on github.

Comment: While I agree with using Ansible to manager WSL instances, the original question is about setting up that initial user in the WSL session when creating a  new Windows host.  Those "minimal steps" that you mention, such as creating the initial user, are exactly what the poster is trying to automate.

Comment: It's indeed not exactly on topic, but thanks for the suggestion. Will look into it after I finish (or give up on) the current script 